# How to view the bash_history for root?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, amazon-ec2

I have a linux box on amazon's aws EC2. I can view the user's bash_history here:

```
/home/ec2-user/.bash_history
```

However when I root in:

```
sudo -s
```

I do not get the root's bash_history. How can I view/find the bash_history for the admin user?

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the history command to see the current users history.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the quick way:

```
sudo less /root/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 1):

When you "sudo -s", you apparently get the .bash_history of the source account, because $HOME is unchanged.

Try setting $HOME to ~root before you sudo -s.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the logging within sudo, by inserting this with visudo

```
Defaults logfile=/var/log/sudo.log
```